# WordPress Theme With Customizable Colours

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I'm currently in the process of trying to convert a Bootstrap single page website I made to a WordPress theme. The part I'd like assistance with is allowing for customizable colours; specifically the primary and secondary colours that are attached to bootstrap.

I've already registered the theme customizer in `functions.php` however I need a way to actually change the colours on the page.

I had considered using something like what I have below, however I have a fair few things that use either the primary or secondary colours and then there's all of bootstrap's own. Is there an easier/faster way to go about this or am I forced to do this?

```
function customize_css() {
    $primary = get_theme_mod('primary_colour', '#F0AEAA');
    $secondary = get_theme_mod('secondary_colour', '#2C3E50');
    ?>
        <style>
            /* PRIMARY COLOUR OVERWRITES */
            a {
                color: <?= $primary ?>;
            }
            .bg-primary {
                background-color: <?= $primary ?> !important;
            }

            /* SECONDARY COLOUR OVERWRITES */
            .bg-secondary {
                background-color: <?= $secondary ?> !important;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'customize_css');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example of code is easiest way to display the background color.

Just, you put the code in functions.php file in your theme.

```html
function customize_css() {
    $primary = get_theme_mod('primary_colour', '#F0AEAA');
    $secondary = get_theme_mod('secondary_colour', '#2C3E50');
    ?>
        <style>
            /* PRIMARY COLOUR OVERWRITES */
            a {
                color: <?= $primary ?>;
            }
            .bg-primary {
                background-color: <?= $primary ?> !important;
            }

            /* SECONDARY COLOUR OVERWRITES */
            .bg-secondary {
                background-color: <?= $secondary ?> !important;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'customize_css');
```

All the Best!!